# P-value for multi-level analysis

Tags: mixed-model, p-value, multilevel-analysis

[image]I conducted a multi-level analysis with mixed model.  The data has 6 countries.  And the sample size of each country (no of respondent in my case) is ranged from 1153 to 1590.  Most results are significant with different p level (p<.05, p<.01, p<.001).  For example,  item A: b= .041,s.e.=.008, p<.001, item B: b=.019, s.e.=.009, p<.05, item C: b=.036,s.e.=.009, p<.001.  Given that the total sample (by summing up all 6 countries) is over 6,000, am I supposed to only use p<.001 as benchmark over result reporting so to avoid type 1 error?
And if the coefficient of the mixed model is smaller than .04 (just like as reported above), can I call it a weak effect, just like a regular correlation, according to Cohen rule?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to CV! There are some important details here missing. First, it's not clear what you mean by the different sample sizes. Could you clarify on that point? Could you include summaries from your analysis which indicate the things you mentioned? I think at minimum this info would be helpful to answering your question.

Comment: I just updated the post.  Does it help for the illustration? @ShawnHemelstrand

Comment: Just so my understanding is correct, you have fit all of this data into one model? And what are the items supposed to be?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand The multilevel model is executed since my data is grouped (or nested) in more than one category (country in my case).  "Item" I referred here is basically the relationship between the IV and DV.  So item 1, 2, 3 has different IV but with the same DV.

Comment: Can you at least share the formula you used in R in your question or a mock version of the formula you used? This unfortunately doesn't help me understand.

Comment: I used SPSS not R.  And I just uploaded the screenshot

Comment: @shawn  https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/01/a-brief-introduction-to-multilevel-modelling/#:~:text=Better%20inferences%3A%20A%20multilevel%20regression,and%20overstatement%20of%20coefficient%20significance.

Comment: I forgot SPSS has this ability too. I'm still confused though because the output you have shared isn't super informative. I'm still confused by what your random effects are, what A through C are, etc. For comparison, this video shows a more detailed view of SPSS output and shows the fixed and random effect estimates rather than just the model parameters: https://youtu.be/RU1ps6jaheI

Comment: I just updated the jpeg again.  Are you able to see the random effect etc at your end?  @ShawnHemelstrand

Answer (score 1):

I've asked a considerable number of questions but it seems like the information I am looking for is still missing. Let me just answer some of the questions you had in hopes that will push you in the right direction while addressing some of what I see. I think the answers were already there for what you asked, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't something terribly off with your model.

First off, the p value cutoffs are arbitrary and largely field specific. In my domain, people tend to use p < .05 cutoffs. That does not change based off sample size (the cutoffs at least). The p values for these predictors will of course change based off how many people you have (generally significant effects are more likely with large samples), but that doesn't say anything about whether or not you should adjust them. The p value cutoffs you use will also depend on what area you work in.

However, none of this will really say anything about the magnitude of the effects like you asked. They are not analogous to Cohen's D and should not be interpreted that way. I don't believe SPSS has effect sizes for mixed models, but you can obtain a pseudo R2 for the model (see [Nakagawa et al., 2017](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsif.2017.0213) and [part R2](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34113487/) for fixed effects to explain what the strength of these effects are. Otherwise a p value says fairly little about that.

Comment: Thanks much for the clarification.